# Javascript raiseEvent for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, raiseevent

I am looking for the alternative to the following piece of code, because it will only work in IE and not in Chrome:

```
window.opener.frames[ "forms_frame"].document.getElementById("forms_applet").raiseEvent("DocumentReady", message);
```

I have found 'trigger' for jquery and came up with this:

```
var formsFrame = window.opener.frames["forms_frame"];
$(formsFrame).contents().find('#forms_applet').trigger("DocumentReady",message);
```

However trigger does not seem to trigger the event on the applet side.
Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: How about: `$(formsFrame).contents().find('#forms_applet').ready(message);`

Comment: Nope don't think that is it because we want to raise an Event called 'DocumentReady' in the applet. I will try to see if it works though...